# If specific string is not included, I want to make some value=0

Tags: r, string

```
df <- data.frame(company = c('B','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7'),
             share = c(0, 0.235, 0.252, 0.063, 0.073, 0.069, 0.022, 0.286))

# create index of all combinations
allcombsindex <- lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
combn(1:length(df$company),x,simplify = F)
})
# get rid of extra level
allcombsindex <- do.call('c',allcombsindex)

# paste together company names and sum the shares
result <- sapply(allcombsindex,function(x,y = df){
c(paste(y$company[x],collapse = ","),
sum(y$share[x]))
})

# transpose upright
data<-as.data.frame(t(result))

# from Factor into Numeric, see the class(data$V2)
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}

# Define market share summation
m<-as.numeric.factor(data$V2)

# And now good looking data frame 
data_working<-data.frame(data$V1,m)

# the limit repertory
# r=0.5, s=0.75
# manual modification is required 
m0<-0.5*(1-0.75)/(1-0.5*0.75)

# append m0 to compare m with m0
data_working2<-data.frame(data_working, m0)

# compare the limit repertoty with existing repertory

compare<-ifelse(data_working2[,2]>data_working2[,3],data_working2[,2],0)

# create the final result
data_immediate<-data.frame(data_working2,compare)

# Now compute surplus from each coalition
# value of 0.75 comes from exponential part of generating surplus

surplusgen<- function(x) x/(1-0.75*(1-(x)))


# compute surplus from each rows

surplus<-sapply(compare, surplusgen)

# One missing point, by definition, without B it generates no surplus. this point should    be considered.
# Firstly, define another data frame to work with it.

data_working3<-data.frame(data_immediata,surplus)
```

What I want to do at this stage is as follows:
I want to make new column and its component's value is zero,
if specific string, say B, is not included data_working3[,1].
if not, its component's value is same as data_working3[,5].

How can I do this?? please help me out.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Then I want to set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ifelse`

```
data_working3$newCol <-  ifelse(grepl("\\bB\\b",data_working3[,1]),
                                         data_working3[,5], 0)
```

or

```
indx <- grepl("\\bB\\b", data_working3[,1])
data_working3$newCol <- 0
data_working3$newCol[indx] <- data_working3[,5][indx]
head(data_working3)
#   data.V1     m  m0 compare   surplus newCol
#1       B 0.000 0.2   0.000 0.0000000      0
#2      m1 0.235 0.2   0.235 0.5513196      0
#3      m2 0.252 0.2   0.252 0.5740319      0
#4      m3 0.063 0.2   0.000 0.0000000      0
#5      m4 0.073 0.2   0.000 0.0000000      0
#6      m5 0.069 0.2   0.000 0.0000000      0
```

Comment: you are just awesome. From the bottom of my heart, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple command to create the new column (`value`):

```
data_working3$value <- data_working3[[5]] * !grepl("B", data_working3[[1]])
```